# ASP.NET Routine to make a Select everyday at midnight

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

So, I'm creating a system in ASP.NET using SQL Server that sends email notification to people about their expiring documents. The user inputs the date of the document and it will warn the user about it's due time 5 days before.

I thought about creating some routine that runs everyday at midnight and (SELECT *) comparing the actual date and the due date. Should I create a Stored Procedure on SQL? Or something in my .CS file that runs with Microsoft Task Scheduler?

Comment: You can use a `sql agent job` and schedule it to run every night at midnight, and have it call a stored procedure which does this select query, and then use `sql-server` to send out the email message.

Comment: Or use a Windows Service. E.g. see [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16335/Simple-Windows-Service-which-sends-auto-Email-aler) or [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ee01e6/create-windows-service-and-send-mail-daily-on-fixed-time-usi575/).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend building a web application to perform a job like this.  In your description, there's no need to implement ASP.NET for any of it.  Look at the recommended options using SQL Server or a Windows Service.

Comment: I suggest that as it is a task that you want to run on a schedule, a scheduled task would be most appropriate. A program written in C# to read from the database would be a good choice for the task.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Thanks, I will try to create a job in SQL Server to do it, the ASP.NET part is for the user to register the title of document, the type of the document and it's expiration date.

Comment: @Pvxtotal Ok,I see what you're saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see it, you don't need an ASP.NET app for this. You can simply have a SQL job running on your SQL Server that runs at midnight, runs your SP (stored procedure) which sends the appropriate email as required. SQL Server has facilities to send emails via SMTP.

If however you want to create something more sophisticated in ASP.NET I would definitely look into using Hangfire, which allows you to have jobs running in background in an ASP.NET application (or not). Hangfire can handle pretty complex job scenarios, have a look here: http://hangfire.io